# E_INVALIDARG in MAP (D3D11)

Tags: c++, directx, screen

Good afternoon.
I am trying to write a program that will display pixels for me from the desktop, but I get an E_INVALIDARG error in the Map function.
Below I have attached my function and indicated with a comment where I got this error. I also inserted the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag in the D3D11CreateDevice function, but it doesn't output anything. Please help.

```
BYTE* GetImageData()
{
    
    if (pDupTex2D != NULL)
    {
        printf("Tap1\n");
        /*
        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC description;
        pDupTex2D->GetDesc(&description);
        description.BindFlags = 0;
        description.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
        description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
        description.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;*/
        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC Desc;
        //Desc.Width = 3440;
        //Desc.Height = 1440;
        Desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
        Desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
        Desc.BindFlags = 0;
        Desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
        pDupTex2D->GetDesc(&Desc);
        ID3D11Texture2D *texTemp = NULL;
        HRESULT hr = pD3DDev->CreateTexture2D(&Desc, NULL, &texTemp);
        std::cout << std::hex<<hr << std::endl;
        
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            if (texTemp)
            {
                texTemp->Release();
                texTemp = NULL;
            }
            return NULL;
        }
        printf("Tap2\n");
        pCtx->CopyResource(texTemp, pDupTex2D);
        D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapped;
        unsigned int subresource = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 0);
        hr = pCtx->Map(texTemp, subresource, D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &mapped); // ERROR ===================================
        std::cout << std::hex << hr << std::endl;
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            texTemp->Release();
            texTemp = NULL;
            return NULL;
        }
        printf("Tap3\n");
        unsigned char* captureData = new unsigned char[Desc.Width * Desc.Height * 4];
        RtlZeroMemory(captureData, Desc.Width * Desc.Height * 4);
        const int pitch = mapped.RowPitch;
        unsigned char* source = static_cast<unsigned char*>(mapped.pData);
        unsigned char* dest = captureData;
        for (int i = 0; i < Desc.Height; i++) {
            memcpy(captureData, source, Desc.Width * 4);
            source += pitch;
            captureData += Desc.Width * 4;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Desc.Width * Desc.Height * 4; i++) {
            printf("h");
            std::cout << "Pixel[%d] = %x\n" << i << dest[i] << std::endl;
        }

        pCtx->Unmap(texTemp, 0);
        return dest;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: First things first is make sure the debug layer really works, you can't develop with DirectX and friends w/o it unless you already master these techs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-layers#debug-layer and it's very possible it will tell you exactly what's wrong once enabled. Other than that, your code too partial to help.

Comment: ``pDupTex2D->GetDesc(&Desc);`` this line means we have no idea what the description is for the actual texture you are creating and trying to map.